# Visual Studio reports wrong line when pause at breakpoint (at stack)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

When my program reach a breakpoint, Visual Studio will report wrong line in below stack calls.
(delay around 1 statement)

It doesn't always happen, but does happen in most locations.
A location of code that have this issue will always have issue.

### Example

There is a breakpoint in `Vector3::setValue()`.
It will be indirectly hit when I call `setTransform()` at line 25:-

```
//inside "doThat()"
if(someValue){
    auto physicObject=getObject();
    if(somefunction()){
        someFunction()
    }else{
        physicObject->setTransform(transform); //line 25 It should pause here. #A

    }
}else{ //line 28  <----- VS reports that it pauses here #C
    printSomeThing()
}
```

The stack-trace will show as:-

```
Vector3::setValue()
Transformation::operator=()
PhysicObject::setTransform()   
System::doThat()    (line 28)    #C
...
```

If I click at `#C`, Visual Studio will highlight `#C`, so I can't investigate value of `physicObject` because `physicObject` is now out-of-scope.

**My workaround**

If I really want to watch `physicObject`, I will have to add a dummy line `#B` :-

```
    }else{
        physicObject->setTransform(transform);   //line 25  #A
        int dummy=42;                            //line 26  #B
    }
```

The stack will report :-

```
System::doThat()    (line 26)    #B
```

I will be able to watch `physicObject`.

### Question

How to make Visual Studio report stack at a correct line?

There are similar questions, but I can't find any one that exactly matches this issue.
 (I have searched periodically for a few months.)

Note that I always turned optimization = off, and I run in debug mode.
Rebuild-all doesn't help either.

Comment: When "walking" through the call-stack I noticed that line marker often is placed in line after call. This is probably caused because this is the next source code line according to address in machine code where the call actually happened. If you want to see it more precise - switch display to disassembly. I finally got used to this effect and just ignore it. (I hardly can imagine how to do it better without other bothering side effects but this might be caused by my limited fantasy.)

Comment: @Scheff  glad to know that I am not alone, thank :)

Comment: @javaLover, whether all projects have this issue or just the specific one? If you enable the Exception settings windows, whether it has any exception messages which were threw?

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT  "just the specific one?" <-  This is my first serious c++ project, so I don't know, sorry. ....     "exception threw?" <- If I open the `Exception Settings` windows, I will found some items are checked (e.g. `C++ Exception\Platform::AccessDeniedException`), some items are not checked (e.g. `Win32 Exception\WinRT Originate Error`)  I have never do anything (and also lack knowledge) about this window ...... Note that when the mentioned issue occurs - there are no exceptions. (i.e. my program run good).

Comment: @javaLover, thanks for your response, the Exception is the possible reason I know, but if still no help, would you please share the detailed code about how I could repro this issue using a simple sample? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Sorry for that I couldn't create this sample using the main code in your question.

Comment: did you try to *Clean* then *Rebuild All*?

Comment: I agree that I should create mcve VS-project as Jack suggest.   A.S.H, I need some days to test it again, thank.   I will do both.  Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @A.S.H I just tried today.  It didn't help.  Nice guess, by the way.  :) .... I just find a new information : disassembly shows a correct "pause" location (while Call Stack is a little wrong).

Comment: @javaLover, would you please create mcve project? So we could repro this issue in our side? Another issue is that whether you could add four different breakpoints from 25 line to 28 line in your code? And then you debug your code with step into(F11), whether you could find any differences? Anyway, share a small sample would be better for me to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT   I agree with everything you said.  I just can't do that in the moment, because my project is undergoing a heavy refactoring.   I still can't  reproduce it in a very tiny project either. I will try harder and ping you after I succeed. (sorry)